# android multiply button case switch

Tags: android, button, toast

I have been looking at some posts and still I cannot get mine code to work (I am a beginner) .. I am just tring to use the toast with my two buttons with a case switch .. When compiling it just crashes .. one something has an idea ?

Code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    TextView et = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);

    Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    Button btnDis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    btnDis.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

}


public void OnClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.btnAdd:
        //  Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Torben", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //   msg.show();
            break;

          case R.id.btnDisplay:
        //    Toast msg1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Henriksen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //       msg1.show();
            break;

           default:

              break;
        }
      }
```

Comment: could you post the exception from LogCat too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two main problems:

```
((OnClickListener) this
```

Make sure your class implements `OnClickListener` because you never need to cast if you are actually implementing the interface.'

The declaration of the class should be something like:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Then change  `OnClick` to lowercase `o`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
```

Answer (score 0):

some log output would be helpful!

a wild guess is that your activiy does not implement OnClickListener, why else would you cast this to OnClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

just check in your layout manifest that whether the buttons id are correct and given the same id which your are using and if it is then please update the question with the LogCat output.

And also check that the activity is defined in manifest because there is no mistake in your code to implemts the onclick listener for multiple buttons.

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

Example adding a button listener:

```
Button b = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button_name));
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                //do something
            }
        });
```

and make sure the button is defined in your xml file with the id @+id/button_name or @id/button_name (just make sure they match)